# Read an integer from a binary file

Tags: java

I need to read an integer from a non-text file in Java.  Here is the equivalent code in C

```
unsigned int MagicNumber;
int fd = open("MyFile", O_RDONLY);
int rc = read(fd, &MagicNumber, 4);
```

What is the equivalent in Java?

This does NOT work for me (it produces different results than the C code):

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("MyFile");
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(fin);
int MagicNumber = din.readInt();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt()

Comment: I know if I read enough about Java then I can figure this out myself.  But I did not find my answer in the links you listed.

Comment: False alarm.  I though I had figured it out, but it's still wrong.

Comment: It looks like Java is flipping the byte order as compared to C.  I think I should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses a machine independent representation of the interger as a byte sequence, if you write it with DataOutputStream and next try to read it with DataInputStream on a different machine even with different endian, it will read it correctly anyway. 
Java was designed exactly for that: i.e. to be machine independent.

Of course you cannot assume the byte sequence will be the same in the file you generated in C.

It happens that Java defaults to big-endian (see the DataOutput specs).
If you do your test on any big-endian machine it will work, on a little-endian (like x86) it will fail.

You can try to use [LittleEndianDataOutputStream](https://guava.dev/releases/17.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/io/LittleEndianDataOutputStream.html) to solve this.